# Admob shows Test ads but not real ads in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm using **AdMob** for showing android ads. The test ads are working fine but real ads are not shown. Also, I've got an issue with real ***interstitial ads*** and ***banner ads*** both are not working.Here is my code :

*banner_ads.xml*

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">

            <!-- i have used a test ads over here -->

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
private AdView mAdView;
AdView = fragView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

<!--for interstitial -->
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
// i have used a test id
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

How to change my code so that real-time ads also appear?

Answer (score 0):

its an improvement by Android Studio 3.0.

> If you run the app to other device admob will start serving real ads

**Edit**
*Note: Your code is ok but you copied test ad code from google website that is why you are getting test ad. To show real ad you need to generate ad code from your google admob account.*

Comment: Hello Thats Enam is there any way to check the ad id which I am using is wrong or right

Comment: @MahakSinghvi i edited the answer. if it helps marking this answer as Solution is one kind of smart work. :)

Comment: I have tried and also replaces the code but it's not showing ads that's why I have asked that question

Comment: @MahakSinghvi oh dear it will take some time to serve real ads. keep patient.

Comment: I have already waited for 30 min but not getting any result :(

Comment: @MahakSinghvi make sure you fill your billing adress info in your admob account. if you did, dont worry it will start serving ad.

Comment: I have already completed all the billing details and earlier I have used the ads they are working fine but in this case, I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for InterstitialAd because you dont written`mInterstitial.show();` in your code

Like this

```
public void inrequestadd() {
    mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
    mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(
            R.string.INTRESTITIAL_ID));
    mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitial.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Last week, i have faced the same situation. Please review the steps.

1_ be sure to use correct publisher and banner id. I dont see publisher id in your code, please visit [admob get started page](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

2_ what is the error? you can find it out in logcat. Or you can implement adlistener to your code and print it like this;

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        // log the error code
    }
});
```

3_if you get error code =0

3.a_some blogs say that; this happens when you create new ad in admob, sometimes it takes 1-2 hours to be worked. So please wait and try again later.

3.b_(this is my situation) i dont know the reason but google banned my package name, so in this situation, your application never be allowed to show any advertisement. Just change your packege name and everything work fine. To check this situation, create new sample project and than copy your admob codes.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting adUnit in both XML and java file avoid that set it in file either java or xml not both.